# modify the static member of a class in java

Tags: java, android

I have encountered a problem that :
I hava a Url.class like this

```
class Url {

public static host = "zh.nurane.otkur.biz";

public static basic_url = host + "/api/v1";
public static addContect = basic_url + "/add";

}
```

and I use this url.addContect in another class

```
class Foo extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart_layout);

    if(somecase){
        Url.HOST = "ug.nurane.otkur.biz";
   }

    System.out.println(Url.addContect  + "   host =" + Url.HOST);
}


}
```

from println I got

"zh.nurane.otkur.biz/api/v1/add   host =ug.nurane.otkur.biz  "

actually I want this result

"ug.nurane.otkur.biz/api/v1/add   host =http://ug.nurane.otkur.biz  "

is it possible to do this ? thanks

Comment: Yes, you can modify static members, as long as they're not declared as `final`. You just have to modify them before you use them. Where are you having trouble modifying a member?

Comment: make changes to all the variables in a static method ?

Comment: public static host = "http://zh.nurane.otkur.biz";

Comment: you can add sth like "onMemberChanged" to deal with the modification. In that method just change value of other members

Comment: your somecase might never be true..

Comment: As I understand it, you just wrote the value to `addContent` once, during declaration. Changing the value in `host`, you want the `addContent` to get updated too. Well, it doesn't work that way. Since those assignments are only exec. once. You will need to make a static method, pass your new `host` value to that method, and rewrite the other variables based on the new `host`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In class Url, add a public static method.

```
public static updateVariablesOnHost(String newHost){
     host = newHost;
     basic_url = host + "/api/v1";
     addContect = basic_url + "/add";
}
```

Call this method to update your `host`, and it should reflect changes in addContent too.

As I understand it, you just wrote the value to `addContent` once, during declaration. Changing the value in `host`, you want the `addContent` to get updated too. Well, it doesn't work that way, since those assignments are only exec. once. You will need to make a static method, pass your new `host` value to that method, and rewrite the other variables based on the new `host`.

**Static is not equivalent to MACROs in C/C++**. What you are expecting is for inline replacement of code, which is effectively a MACRO, and using static will not help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your `Url` class don't have `HOST` it only has `host`.

Now for your question, why don't you change

this

```
Url.HOST = "ug.nurane.otkur.biz";
```

to

```
Url.HOST = "http://ug.nurane.otkur.biz";
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer to your question: yes you can modify static variables but your problem has nothing to do with static variables. If you create a class for holding ONLY some static variables you might want to make them *final* and create two variables:

```
public static final HOST_1= "zh.nurane.otkur.biz";
public static final HOST_2= "ug.nurane.otkur.biz";
```

In your activity check the *somecase* condition and access whichever host you need to. Overall try to follow Java coding convention. Compound attribute names are distinguished by capitalizing first character of each word like this:

```
public basicUrl = host + "/api/v1";
```

But that sounds more like a constant therefore the following convention applies:

```
 public static final BASIC_URL= host + "/api/v1";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give you proper understanding of what static is.

When you declare any variable static system keeps only one variable in memory of the static data. Irrelevant of number object you make for that particular class.

In your case you tries to change the `Url.host`'s values. System has changed the value.
But its is not reflected because you have previously stored `Url.host`'s value to `basic_url` and `addContect`. These two variable already got the memory and value compile time.

Thats why your change is not reflected in `Url.addContect`.

You have to reassign every value each time you modify your static data.

I hope I have cleared your confusion.

And please post your correct code. I can't see String in your declaration. 
It should be.

```
public static String host = "zh.nurane.otkur.biz";
```